# Google Cloud Functions - Nodejs error , forever loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

```
const request = require('request');

exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld(req, res) {
    var headers = {
    'scheme': 'https',
    'authorization': 'Token 123',
    'user-agent': 'mobile'
    };
    var options = {
        url: 'https://url',
        headers: headers
    };
    function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
        res.status(200).send(response.body);
        }
    }
    request(options, callback);
};
```

I can submit a request without issue, but once i start doing a request with headers and options , i cant get it to work properly on Google Cloud Function.

Please advice on my mistake

Trigger type
: HTTP trigger

Comment: May be `'': 'scheme: https',` is invalid

Comment: @brk i need it to be https

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that an error is being returned from the call you're making using `request`, and since in the error case you don't end the function using res.end() or res.status(500).end(), Cloud Functions doesn't know if your function is done or not, so just runs it until a timeout is hit.

Try:

```
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  console.log(body);
  res.status(200).send(response.body);
} else {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(500).send(error);
}
```

You should get a response back without the Cloud Function hanging.